# Add www subdomain to S3 and Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have followed this article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html#root-domain-walkthrough-s3-tasks but I am unable to get my www domain to resolve.

I have completed the following:

- Created two s3 buckets named after my domain. My content is in the www bucket which is configured to host a site and is functional from the aws endpoint. The apex bucket is configured to redirect to the www bucket and it is doing that correctly.
- I have also created 2 hosted zones and given each of them an Alias record that points to their respective buckets.
- Lastly, I have configured my domain (registered though Route 53) to point to the namespace servers that my apex hosted zone gives me.

At this point, everything is redirecting properly but my www domain does not resolve. I tried adding a CNAME to the hosted zone but the console will not allow it.

I know I am missing something, but I am not sure what. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > I have also created 2 hosted zones and given each of them an Alias record that points to their respective buckets.

You don't need two zones, just one.  Delete then zone with www in it and create the www resource record in the remaining zone.

Comment: I literally just figured this out but yes you are right. The answer was to add an alias for the www domain to the apex domain's hosted zone. I deleted the second hosted zoner as it appears not to be necessary.